# Biblatex issues: citation nicknames showing up in document and no reference section being produced

Tags: biblatex, errors

I am receiving this error message whenever I compile by LaTeX document:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Final Paper.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Final Paper.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Final Paper.aux
```

My preamble contains this command for my bibliography:

```
\bibliography{Psy 290.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{\normalfont\refname}}
```

In my document, I am using `\parencite` and `\textcite` for referencing. I have also tried `\cite`, `\citet`, and `\citep` and just receive another error message stating those commands are not recognized. Does anybody have any insight into what may be happening?

Comment: `\bibliography` is the command for the older interface to `bibtex`.  In `biblatex` you need to use `\addbibresource`.  Please a complete minimal document [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you load and use `biblatex`.

Comment: You probably need to run biber instead of bibtex. `\citet` and `\citeb` works only if you load biblatex with the option natbib.

Comment: @AndrewSwann `\bibliography` works with `biblatex` (although in a modified manner compared to standard LaTeX): that alone isn't the issue.

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed, but it is deprecated, and the poster needs to give us more information about loading and set-up.